# С# MVVM WPF Добавление и удаление в DateGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

View

```
    <Window x:Class="Person_Changed.MainWindow"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
            xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
            xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
            xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
            xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Person_Changed"
            xmlns:human="clr-namespace:Person_Changed.ViewModel"
            mc:Ignorable="d"
            Title="MainWindow" Height="355.263" Width="493.421">
        <Window.DataContext>
            <human:HumanViewModel/>
        </Window.DataContext>
        <Grid Margin="0,0,2,-5">
            <ListView 
                x:Name="listView"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Humans }"
                Margin="10,122,10,10">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Ид"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Id}"         Width="60" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Имя"     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding FirstName}"  Width="70" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Фамилия" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SurName}"    Width="80" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Паспорт" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Passport}"   Width="100" />
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Дата"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding DataBirth}"  Width= "150" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
            <Button  
                Content="Добавить"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="161,0,0,283"
                Width="84"
                Command="{Binding AddHuman}"
                BorderThickness="0" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>

            <TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Text="{Binding FirstName,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10,10,0,0"/>
            <TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Text="{Binding SurName,    UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10,38,0,0"/>
            <TextBox  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Text="{Binding Passport,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"  VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="10,66,0,0"/>
            <DatePicker HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="20" Text="{Binding DataBirth,   UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="10,93,0,0" Width="120" FontSize="10" FontFamily="Times New Roman"/>
            <Button  
                Content="Удалить"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="161,0,0,230"
                Width="84"
                BorderThickness="0" Height="36" VerticalAlignment="Bottom"/>


        </Grid>
    </Window>
```

Human

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;

namespace Person_Changed.Model
{
    public class Human : ObservableObject
    {
        private int _id;
        private string _firstname;
        private string _surname;
        private string _passport;
        private DateTime _databirth;



        #region property
        public int Id
        {
            get { return _id; }
            set
            {
                _id = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Id);
            }
        }
        public string FirstName
        {
            get { return _firstname; }
            set
            {
                _firstname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => FirstName);
            }
        }
        public string SurName
        {
            get { return _surname; }
            set
            {
                _surname = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SurName);
            }
        }
        public string Passport
        {
            get { return _passport; }
            set
            {
                _passport = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => Passport);
            }
        }

        //[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString ="{0:dd'/'MM'/'yyyy}",ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
        public DateTime DataBirth
        {
            get { return _databirth; }
            set
            {
                _databirth = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => DataBirth);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

HumanViewModel

```
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight;
using GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;
using Person_Changed.Model;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Person_Changed.ViewModel
{
    class HumanViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        public ObservableCollection<Human> Humans { get; set; }
        private Human _selectedhuman;

        public Human SelectedHuman
        {
            get { return _selectedhuman; }
            set
            {
                _selectedhuman = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedHuman);
            }
        }
        public HumanViewModel()
        {

            DateTime newdate = new DateTime(2018, 01, 01);
            Humans = new ObservableCollection<Human>
            {
                new Human {Id = 1, FirstName="Иван", SurName = "Иванов", Passport = "1111-111111", DataBirth = newdate}
            };
        }

        private ICommand _addhuman;
        public ICommand AddHuman
        {
            get
            {
                return _addhuman ?? (_addhuman = new RelayCommand(() => 
                {
                    Human human = new Human();
                    Humans.Add(human);
                }));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Цель - Добавить значение в коллекцию DataGrid из textbox'ов

У меня почему-то не перехватывается биндинги полей и заполняется нулями
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну во-первых, у вас в `HumanViewModel` нет свойств `FirstName`/`SurName`/etc, привязка, естественно, не работает. Ну и в `AddHuman` вы же не заполняете никакие свойства у созданного объекта: `Human human = new Human(); Humans.Add(human);`

Comment: @АндрейNOP  И как тогда объявить свойства если я их уже объявлял в моделях и как заполнить в add(human)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите, тут все очень просто! Вы на "холсте" размещаете `ListView`, пару `Button`, несколько `TextBox` и `DatePicker`. Отлично, все они ожидают свое свойство в указанном как `DataContext` классе. Смотрим, какой класс мы указали:

```
<Window.DataContext>
    <human:HumanViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
```

`HumanViewModel` - это наша главная ViewModel, на нее все ссылаются.

Хорошо, пойдем дальше, пройдемся по всем нашим объектам на холсте и сравним с тем, что есть в главной VM:

- ListView - данный контрол ожидает в `ItemsSource` коллекцию, вы указываете `Humans`, смотрим в главную VM и действительно, видим ее там `public ObservableCollection<Human> Humans { get; set; }`.

  - Внутри ListView вы задаете `GridViewColumn` - эти объекты будут брать за главную VM тот объект, который лежит внутри коллекции (у вас это `<Human>`).
- Button - в роди команды ожидает свойство типа `ICommand`, вы указываете `AddHuman`, проверяем и да, опять находим: `public ICommand AddHuman`.
- TextBox - Text, это string значение, а значит ищем string свойство в нашей `HumanViewModel`, вы привязываете это все к `FirstName`, ищем и его в VM нету, а значит этому текстовому полю уже попросту не к чему привязываться.

Напомню, что все объекты привязываются к свойствам из класса, который задан как `DataContext`!

Надеюсь с этим мы разобрались. Теперь посмотрим на кнопку добавления, вы там делаете следующее:

```
Human human = new Human();
Humans.Add(human);
```

То есть вы берете, создаете новый, пустой объект Human и добавляете его (пустой) в коллекцию. Что то вы тут забыли, заполнение? Не удивительно, что вы видите пустые объекты!

Теперь как это все решить:

- Как вариант, это создать все свойства для TextBox'ов (Id, FirstName, SurName, Passport, DataBirth) в главной ViewModel и при добавление указывать их значения.
- Еще вариант, это создание отдельного свойства (`public Human SelectedHuman {get;set;} = new Human();`), которое будет использоваться для TextBox'ов (`{Binding SelectedHuman.Id}`), а также для выделенного элемента самого ListView (`SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedHuman}"`). Добавление тогда у вас будет простое `Humans.Add(SelectedItem);`, да и удаление тоже (`Humans.Remove(SelectedItem);`).

Подытожив все это, имеем две проблемы:

1. Привязка к несуществующим свойствам.
2. Добавление пустого объекта в коллекцию.

В общем удачи в изучении WPF!

Comment: Спасибо за понятный ответ, но этот способ мне не походит так как если например поля должны фильтроваться например: Паспорт 1111-111111, дата иметь 01-01-2000 или как то еще. В этом способе, никак условие не поставишь так как сначала добавляется строка, а после она заполняется значениями из поля.

Comment: Имя, фамилия - обязательны, не более 25 символов, разрешены русские буквы, дефис и пробел
Отчество - необязательно, не более 25 символов, разрешены русские буквы, дефис и пробел
Номер паспорта - обязателен, в формате 4 цифры серии + 6 цифр номера
Дата рождения - обязательна

Comment: дата рождения в формате "дд.мм.гггг" (пример: 12.06.2018)  
номер паспорта в формате серия-номер (пример: 1234-567890)

Comment: @Tim Это уже другой вопрос и тоже легко делается в Set нужного свойства. Сейчас мы говорим именно про `У меня почему-то не перехватывается биндинги полей и заполняется нулями` и я как можно подробнее постарался до вас донести ваши две существенные ошибки. Что и как вы дальше реализуете - это уже совсем другая история )

Comment: Я понял, спасибо большое)

Comment: Простите, а можно по подробней про " тоже легко делается в Set нужного свойства."

Comment: @Tim Самое банальное - [это](https://pastebin.com/mYTUBd4c). Чуть сложней и по уму - [это](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/14.php).